# ASP.NET MVC: Problem with loop in razor view - some code being output

Tags: razor

I am attempting to write a simple loop in a Razor view but the correct layout seems to have alluded me thus far.

My code is as follows:

```
    @using RelensterV3.Helpers

@Html.BeginForm("SaveStockAnswers", "Call", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return false;" }) {
<div class="ui-grid-c">
    @{
        int Count = 1;
        string ClassToApply = "";
    }
    @foreach (var product in Model.StockAnswers)
    {

        if (Count == 1)
        {
            ClassToApply = "ui-block-a";
        }

        if (Count == 2)
        {
            ClassToApply = "ui-block-b";
        }

        if (Count == 3)
        {
            ClassToApply = "ui-block-c";
            Count = 0;
        }
        Count++;

        <div class="stock-product @ClassToApply">
            @*<h2>@product.Product.Name</h2>*@
            @Html.Partial("_StockAnswerForm", product)
        </div>   
    }
</div>
}
```

However, the output of that is as follows:

```
<form action="/Call/SaveStockAnswers" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm {
<div class="ui-grid-c">
        <div class="stock-product ui-block-a">

            <input type="hidden" name="stock.index" autocomplete="off" value="f8befb95-b30d-45bd-bc0e-6214d2001769" />
    <div>.....etc etc
```

Which ends with a trailing curly brace. I'm not sure why these snippets are being output.

Thanks

Comment: thanks I was working with asp.net mvc and jquery mobile today and repurposed the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgeting the `using` statement at the beginning of your html form declaration. Rewrite it as

```
@using(Html.BeginForm ... etc, etc
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(etc..))
{
    // Your loop code
}
```